# 2 paginated lists on 1 page (Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

I have a page in rails app that contains 2 partials with 2 paginated lists (using AJAX).

My controller:

```
  def show
    @movies = @movies.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    @books = @books.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
```

My view (show.html.haml):

```
.row
  .col-md-6.movies-table
    = render partial: 'movies'
  .col-md-6.books-table
    = render partial: 'books'

:javascript
  $(function() {
    $(".movies-table").on("click", '.pagination a', function(){
      $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
      return false;
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $(".books-table").on("click", '.pagination a', function(){
      $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Show.js.erb:

```
$(".movies-table").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("nodes")) %>");
$(".books-table").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("edges")) %>");
```

**Issue: The lists are somehow connected (when I click next page for movies, next page for books is also loading). I want pagination to work separately for these lists.**

Comment: You're using kaminari right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so a quick look in the [docs](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation) suggests you can do this in your controller; have explicit methods just for the pagination.

```
class FooController
  def show
    paginate_movies
    paginate_books    
  end

  def paginate_movies
    @movies = @movies.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end

  def paginate_books
    @books = @books.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can pass the controller and method parameters to `will_paginate`

```
<%= will_paginate @movies, params: { controller: "foo", action: "paginate_movies" } %>
<%= will_paginate @books, params: { controller: "foo", action: "paginate_books" } %>
```

Comment: Is it possible just to rename params[:page]? For example params[:page_1] & params[:page_2]?

Comment: It is, but the issue you have is that because it's using the show action it's performing both sql queries regardless.  You wouldn't have your issue, but renaming the paging parameter would mean you'd still do two sql queries regardless of which you're paginating.

Comment: I created 2 new routes, but it says "Missing template"

Comment: You'll need to split your `show.js.erb`, one for each route.